# Choose one correct answer

Tags: grammar

He respects everyone, so he is highly ( respected _ respectable) 
I see it's respectable as it's related to being good behavior

Answer (score 3):

To describe someone who consistently shows respect for others, the correct word is **respectful.**

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/respectful

> **respectful**
>
> adjective
>
> 1. full of, characterized by, or showing politeness or deference: a respectful reply.

The other words you suggest (respected, respectable) both describe a person who *receives* respect.  (Although, hopefully, a person who shows respect toward others should and would receive respect in return.)

EDIT:

To apply to your original question,

"He respects everyone, so he is highly **respectful toward** all."

Comment: Actually, "respectable" generally means "*worthy* of respect" -- doesn't imply that he gets or gives respect.  And many people who are "respected" (at least by some people) are far from "respectable".

Comment: @HotLicks, good points on both counts.  I had the distinction in the back of my mind but glossed over it when writing up the answer.

Comment: Thanks. If the example is edited to be ( He respects everyone, so he is highly .... by all. ) what's the answer, please?

Comment: Just edited to add that.